# How to fix an expected } error at the end of input

Tags: c++

The program is a Linked List program and everything ran before I had to make some major changes to the program. When debugging the program everything went smooth until the last line of the code which gave this error:

|175|error: expected '}' at end of input|

Just want to see what could be the major problem for the code.

I tried to space out the program individually to see if I missed an input somewhere but I'm not able to find anything wrong.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class node

{
    public:
        string name,id;
        int age;
        node *next;
        void add();
        void takeout();
        void look();
        void display();

    node(string n,string i,int a)
    {
        name=n;
        id=i;
        age=a;
        next=NULL;
    }

};

class Linkedlist{
   private:
       node *list;

   public:
       Linkedlist(){
           list = NULL;
       }

void add() // adds the information for the linked list
{
    string s,i;
    int a;
    cout << "\nEnter the student's information below.\n";
    cout << "Student's Name : ";
    cin >> s;
    cout << "Student's ID : ";
    cin >> i;
    cout << "Student's Age : ";
    cin >> a;

    node *t = new node(s,i,a);

    //adding front
    t->next=list;
    list=t;
}

void takeout()
{
    string a;
    cout << "\nEnter the Student's ID so their info can be removed. \n";
    cout << "Student's ID : ";
    cin >> a;

    node *prev=NULL,*temp=list;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        if(temp->id==a)
        {
           cout<<"Found.\n";
            break;
        }
        prev=temp;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    if(temp==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"\nInformation not found.\n";
    }
    else if(prev==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"Delinked1\n";
        list=list->next;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Delinked2\n";
        prev->next=temp->next;
    }
}

void look()
{
    string a;
    cout << "\nEnter Student's ID to search for their information.\n ";
    cout << "Student's ID : ";
    cin >> a;

    node *temp=list;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        if(temp->id==a)
        {
        //diplyaing result
        cout << "\n------------------------------\n";
        cout << "Name :" << temp->name << endl;
        cout << "ID :" << temp->id << endl;
        cout << "Age :" << temp->age << endl;
        cout << "\n------------------------------\n";
        break;
        }

        temp=temp->next;
    }
    if(temp==NULL)
    {
        cout << "\nInformation on found.\n";
    }
}

void display()
{
    node *temp=list;
    if(temp==NULL)
        cout<<"\nLIST IS EMPTY---\n";
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        //displaying
        cout << "\n------------------------------\n";
        cout << "Name :" << temp->name << endl;
        cout << "Age :" << temp->age << endl;
        cout << "\n------------------------------\n";

        temp=temp->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Linkedlist list;
    cout << "Student Information (Linked List)\n\n";
    while(1)
    {
        int choice;
        cout << "\n1. Add a node." << endl;
        cout << "2. Delete a node." << endl;
        cout << "3. Search a node." << endl;
        cout << "4. Display a node." << endl;
        cout << "Enter your choice : ";
        cin >> choice;
        cout << endl;
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                list.add();
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                list.takeout();
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                list.look();
                break;
            }
            case 4:
            {
                list.display();
                break;
            }
            default:
                cout << "Wrong choice!" << endl;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I know what the code is suppose to show at the end because I ran it before I had to change the inputs but now with this error the program wouldn't run.

Comment: Show the full code please.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce after adding a simple struct definition](https://godbolt.org/z/JLrNQz). Please provider a [mcve]

Comment: Assuming `175` is the line number, your error probably occurs in the code before `main` that you haven't given us :-) Suggest you do so, or simply check brace balance with whatever editor you're using (such as using `%` in `vim`, which goes to the other end of the current brace).

Comment: `"This is the line where I'm getting the error."` - perhaps -- but that is not the line generating the error and neither are any you posted (your braces are balanced in the code you show). The problem occurs above `main()` in the source file and should be simple to diagnose in most editors that provide *bracket-highlight* -- just go through confirming each set.

Comment: Just added the full code. I'm currently revising to see if I missed anything be int main.

Comment: Just answered with the missing `'}'`

Comment: I would count open and closed braces before `main`. If you had used the proper alignment you would not ask this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Linkedlist{
  private:
    node *list;

  public:
    Linkedlist(){
        list = NULL;
    }
```

Oops.... No closing `'}'`

Though not a requirement by any means, I always found providing consistent formatting with a space between the expression and opening brace helpful to my ability to quickly scan a file and confirm brace balance, e.g.

```
class Linkedlist {
  private:
    node *list;

  public:
    Linkedlist() {
        list = NULL;
    }
    ...
};      /* <== this is the missing closing-brace in your code */
```

And, actually, what has occurred in your case is you are missing the closing brace for the class that includes all member functions below, e.g.

```
class Linkedlist {
  private:
    node *list;

  public:
    Linkedlist() {
        list = NULL;
    }

    void add() // adds the information for the linked list
    {
        ...
    void display()
    {
        node *temp=list;
        if(temp==NULL)
            cout<<"\nLIST IS EMPTY---\n";
        while(temp!=NULL)
        {
            //displaying
            cout << "\n------------------------------\n";
            cout << "Name :" << temp->name << endl;
            cout << "Age :" << temp->age << endl;
            cout << "\n------------------------------\n";

            temp=temp->next;
        }
    }
};      /* <== this is the actual missing closing-brace in your code */
```

Consistent indenting would help identify that problem. Your code compiles just find after adding the closing `'}'`.

An addition to your menu would be nice as well:

```
1. Add a node.
2. Delete a node.
3. Search a node.
4. Display a node.
5. Exit.                 // exit would be nice
Enter your choice :
```

Comment: Thank you very much. When revising the old code that it was included but I didn't input it in the the new code that I was working on. I just was going to say that I solved it but you beat me too it. Thank you very much again for the help.

Comment: Sure, it has happened to us all -- that's when you find out whether you need a new editor or not. (one that will highlight opening and closing brackets). Nothing fancy is needed, when you move the cursor next to an opening bracket, it should highlight, and the closing bracket should highlight as well. If the one you are next to fails to highlight -- you know there is no closing bracket. (default behavior for most syntax highlighting editors) Good luck with your coding.